# Quantity in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, stock

Dear stackoverflow code experts. I have a query relating to opencart stock.

The frontend product page has option of displaying Stock, either in terms of availability (Available or Out of Stock) or in terms of quantity in actual numbers.

Is it possible to display it in some other way? eg. I want that if the stock quantity is less than or equal to 5, then it should display quantity, else display the text: Available.

Or in a more sophisticated manner, if product quantity is greater than 5 or zero, then display text, else display quantity in number.

I understand it may have to do something with ../catalog/controller/product/product.php file.

I am not an expert in coding. Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.

First set "display stock" to Yes

```
admin panel>system>setting>options set display stock to "YES"
```

now

```
//catalog>controller>product>product.php
```

Find (around line 282)

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
 $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
 $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
} else {
 $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
}
```

Replace With

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
 $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display') && $product_info['quantity'] <= 5) {
 $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
} else {
 $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `catalog/controller/product/category.php`

**Step : 1**

Find the code:

```
if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
} else {
    $rating = false;
}
```

Add the following just below the above code :

```
if ($result['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $rstock = $result['stock_status'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
    $rstock = "Stoc: " . $result['quantity'];
} else {
    $rstock = "In stoc";
}
```

**Step : 2**

Find :

```
'thumb' => $image,
```

Add the following just after the above line

```
'stoc' => $rstock,
```

**Step 3**

Edit the file `catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/template/product/category.tpl`

Find :

```
<div class="cart">
```

Add the following :

```
<?php echo $product['stoc']; ?>
```

And now the stock will appear for products in category page.

You can do the same for search (the files would be search.php and search.tpl - in the same folders as the category)

You can see a more detailed tutorial at :

1. http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/09/09/742/
2. http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=27137
3. http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=66506

All of the above uses the same idea, but implemented in different ways. But this should help you solve your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not put properly or maybe i have not understood the reply properly. I am happy with OC defaults in the category or search or any other page. Its only in the individual product page where it says "Availability". It says either "available" or "out of stock". Or if we set yes to display of quantity then it shows numbers. Its only in that one field i want to display number if stock is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 else display the standard text "available" if qty more than 5 or display text "out of stock".